# AngularJS remembering "old" scope values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app where the user can select an item from a list. They are then taken to a another screen which contains a select element whose contents are based on the selection from the first screen. I select an item from this select element and it updates some text fields on screen and everything works fine.

The problem I have is if I go BACK to the first screen and pick a different item from the list, the select element on the 2nd page along with the text fields still have the "old" item actively selected and the text fields display the "old" data.

How do I tell Angular to forget about previous selections, which are no longer in scope? Do I manually have to reset all the fields when I click "Back"?

Comment: Without looking at the code, it will be very difficult to help. Could you share a plunker demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the scope:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {text:'learn angular', done:true},
        {text:'build an angular app', done:false}
    ];

    $scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.data);

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
    };
}
```